# Adding multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, grouping

Just getting familiar with pandas and I'm having an issue with `groupby`.

I have some CSV data that I've munged into the following format:

`Time, AAA, BBB, AAA, BBB
20161201 9:00:00, 10, 20, 11, 21
20161201 9:00:01, 10, 20, 11, 21
20161201 9:00:02, 10, 20, 11, 21`

I want to transform it to the following:

`Time, AAA, BBB
20161201 9:00:00, 21, 41
20161201 9:00:01, 21, 41
20161201 9:00:02, 21, 41`

I'm using the following:

`df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).sum()`

What I get instead is:

`AAA, BBB, Time
21, 41, 0.0
21, 41, 0.0
21, 41, 0.0`

1. How can I prevent pandas from summing the Time column?  I tried the following:

   `df.groupby([c for c in df.columns if c != "Time"], axis=1).sum()`

   but that gives the error:

   `Grouper for 'AAA' not 1-dimensional`
2. How can I avoid pandas moving the Time column?

If it matters, I combined two pandas DataFrames together to get the above data using:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how="outer")
```

And then renamed some columns to shorten the names so I could group them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df.set_index('Time').groupby(axis=1, level=0).sum().reset_index()

               Time  AAA  BBB
0  20161201 9:00:00   21   41
1  20161201 9:00:01   21   41
2  20161201 9:00:02   21   41
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is cleaner without the lambda.

Comment: @MindJuice glad we could help!

Answer (score 2):

You can set `Time` as index:

```
df.set_index("Time").pipe(lambda x: x.groupby(x.columns, axis=1).sum())
```

[image]

Call `reset_index` later, if you want it to be a column in the result.

Comment: Thanks, that works to give me the right columns, but generating CSV just gives me a single line with the text: `Time` with none of the data.  I'm using `csv_out = StringIO()   df.to_csv(csv_out)`

Comment: How are you generating the csv? `df.set_index("Time").pipe(lambda x: x.groupby(x.columns, axis=1).sum()).reset_index().to_csv("somefile")`? Notice when you run the above line, `df` is not modified, you need to call `to_csv` on the new data frame after this line.

Comment: The `reset_index()` was the missing bit.  It's working as I want now!  Thank you!